# Output to screen and csv format python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a python nested dictionary output, I have been able to remove the first set of cruly brackets using RocketDict, but 1) I can't remove the second set of curly brackets 2)I tried to export it to a csv file giving the column names and that doesn't work because I can't figure out how to get the *int#/#* values that increment in the rows.  For Example here was my initial output:

Before RocketDict:

```
{ intx/x : {'value1: 'A', 'value2: 'B', value3: 'C'},
  inty/y : {'value1: 'X', 'value2: 'Y', value3: 'Z'}}
```

After the RocketDict:

```
  intx/x : {'value1: 'A', 'value2: 'B', value3: 'C'},
  inty/y : {'value1: 'X', 'value2: 'Y', value3: 'Z'}
```

Desired output:

```
  intx/x : 'value1: 'A', 'value2: 'B', value3: 'C',
  inty/y : 'value1: 'X', 'value2: 'Y', value3: 'Z'
```

Desired output to the csv:

[image: CSV Sample]

Here is the full script:

```
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
inventory = results.json()
data = inventory['config']

class RocketDict(UserDict):
    def __str__(self):
        r = ['']
        r.extend(['\t{} : {}'.format(k, v)
            for k, v in self.items()])
        return ',\n'.join(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
#standard dict object
#    inventory = {('key-%02d' % v): v for v in range(1, 10)}
#    print(inventory, '\n')
# Wrap that dict object into a RocketDict.
    d2 = RocketDict(data)
    print(d2)

csv_columns = ['value1','value2','value3']
dict_data = d2
csv_file = 'mycsv.csv'
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(d2)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas -

```
RocketDict ={ 'intx/x' : {'value1': 'A', 'value2': 'B', 'value3': 'C'},
    'inty/y' : {'value1': 'X', 'value2': 'Y', 'value3': 'Z'}}
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(RocketDict).transpose().to_csv('out.csv', index =True)
```

Comment: Thank you, so I had to take out the RocketDict because that was totally messing up the formatting.  After taking it out it is now giving me partially the output in CSV that I want.  It is giving me the "value1, 2, 3" columns.  However on the far left side it is not showing me the "intx/x and inty/y".  Is there a way to get that in there as well?

Comment: I changed index=False to index=True and I think that did the job.  Will confirm after running few samples.